# Fuzzy Duplicate Finding with SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, fuzzy-search, sql-like, sqlite3-ruby

this is my first post and I'm something of a novice.

I'm trying to extract a list of fuzzy duplicates from and table of company names using SQLite with sqlite3.

For example, for a company like 'ZtPay' I'm currently using:

```
SELECT name FROM tab WHERE name LIKE 'Z_Pay');

SELECT name FROM tab WHERE name LIKE 'Zt_ay');
```

etc...
To account for typos.

My problem is that if there is no typo then I just output the original company name. Ideally I would like only to output the original name if there was a fuzzy duplicate found by the LIKE.

I know this is very wrong but I want something along the lines of:

```
SELECT name FROM tab WHERE name LIKE 'Z_Pay' IF ATLEAST 2 name LIKE 'Z_Pay'
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine if there is more than one name by looking at the `min()` and `max()`:

```
SELECT name 
FROM tab 
WHERE name LIKE 'Zt_ay%' 
group by name
having min(name) <> max(name)
```

Alternatively, you could use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT name 
FROM tab 
WHERE name LIKE 'Zt_ay%' 
group by name
having count(distinct name) > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I needed to be more specific. For example, I have these 3 entries.

Complete Business Services 
Camplete Business Services
ZTPay 

I only want to output Complete Business Services & Camplete Business services, i.e the Original and the fuzzy, but not ZTPay as it has no fuzzy.

Comment: @AmmanSinghSohi . . . Your question (as I interpret it) says that you have the logic for the fuzzy matches and are trying to return the cases where there is a similar name.  If you don't really have that logic, I'd suggest asking another question and including sample data and expected results.

Comment: @GordronLinoff My logic's problem is that as well as returning a fuzzy and a correct record together (Complete and Camplete), it will return a correct record (ZTPay) that has no fuzzy. I would only like to see correct records if they have a fuzzy. I know this next code is wrong but it explains what I'd like
IF count(Name LIKE 'C_omplete Business Services') > 1 
SELECT Name FROM Real WHERE Name LIKE 'C_mplete Business Services' 

That way no records without fuzzys would be produced as every record with a fuzzy would have at least 2 results for the LIKE search. 

Thank you again for your time.

Comment: @AmmanSinghSohi . . . What you describe is what these `having` clauses do.

Comment: @GordronLinoff 

HAVING does not seem to work for me. For example,

SELECT Name FROM tab 
WHERE name LIKE '_ntertek'
GROUP BY name
HAVING count(name) > 1;
; 

If I had three names, Intertek, Ontertek and Entertek, this HAVING clause would return no results. I want to say something like, 

SELECT Name FROM tab 
WHERE name LIKE '_ntertek'
GROUP BY name
HAVING count(name LIKE '_ntertek') > 1;
; 

How would I achieve this? Thanks once more for your time, it much appreciated.

Comment: I realise it may be worth mentioning that there are no exact duplicates in the data, only fuzzy ones. Therefore there are no duplicate fuzzies. E.g Micrsoft, Microsaft & Microseft could be present, but Microsoft, Microsaft & Microsaft could not be.

Comment: @AmmanSinghSohi: Do you want to return *all* the fuzzy names or just one (when they are more than one)? If only one, then which?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't being clear on that part so posted it in another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532083/sqlite-fuzzy-duplicate-search-using-like/17541735?noredirect=1#17541735